# Laravel 5.4 - JSON contains null bytes (\u000) ����

Tags: php, laravel, unicode, mysql-workbench

I hope you can help me with this.

I used:

1. **Mysql workbench 5.6 with (  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
           'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
           )**
2. **Laravel 5.4**

I have a controller (GetDataController.php)that will call stored procedure, 
below is the code:

```
function getData(){
    $data= DB::select('call spGetAllData()');
    return Response::json(['message' => $data], 200);
}
```

api.php

```
Route::get('showAllData','GetDataController@getData)
```

The result after accessing it via browser:

```
���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������{"message":[{"ID":1,"Data":"data001"},{"ID":2,"Data":"data002"},{"ID":3,"Data":"data003"}]}
```

Tried using **utf8_encode(),json_decode/encode** but still no luck.

**EDIT FOR dd($data) result;**

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => {#221 ▼
    +"ID": 1
    +"Data": "data001"
  }
  1 => {#224 ▼
    +"ID": 2
    +"Data": "data002"
  }
  2 => {#226 ▼
    +"ID": 3
    +"Data": "data003"
  }
]
```

Comment: What does $data look like? Just do a dd($data).

Comment: @Mick I will edit my post to show the result of dd($data)

Comment: @Mick see edits above

Comment: Does it work ok, if you just do a SELECT? I don't think many people use stored procs with Laravel. I do it like this, maybe try this: ```return response()->json(['error' => 'No faults assigned to this process/stream.'], 404);```

Comment: do you mean raw queries? not using SP?

Comment: Yes, a raw ```SELECT * FROM``` or use Eloquent. Most Laravel developers use Eloquent.

Comment: Tried raw queries ,eloquent and return response()->json(['error' => 'No faults assigned to this process/stream.'], 404); still ��� are showing

Comment: See "Black diamond" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: I already fixed this problem.
I exported new dump file from other server and set my schema to UTF-8 default collation